# XSLT to transform XML to XHTML

Tags: xml, xslt, xhtml, xslt-1.0

Definitely I will never find success thinking in XSLT...

Here is what I have:

```
   <par font="Arial" size="24">text 24</par>
   <par font="Arial" size="12">text 12</par>
   <par font="Times New Roman" size="12">text times 12</par>
```

And here is what I want:

```
   <font style="font-family:Arial"><font style="font-size:24">text 24</font></font>
   <font style="font-family:Arial"><font style="font-size:12">text 12</font></font>
   <font style="font-family:Times New Roman"><font style="font-size:12">text times 12</font></font>
```

Of course, something like this is good as well, but for me this solution seems more complicated:

```
<font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:24">text 24</font>
<font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12">text 12</font>
<font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12">text times 12</font>
```

I think (but I may be wrong) I will have to specify some code for each size and each font. This is not a problem because there are only few sizes and fonts available in my xml.

Many many thanks for your help, I start loosing my hair trying to do it by myself...

Comment: Which output do you really want? Multiple `<font>` (your first output example) or a single `<font>` (your second output example)?

Comment: Also, will the **par** element always have both a **font** attribute and a **size** attribute, or is it possible for it to have one of the attributes missing (e.g. a par with only a font, but not a size)?

Comment: @ Tim C : PAR Elements may not have font or size or any attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**XML Input** (modified to be well-formed)

```
<doc>
    <par font="Arial" size="24">text 24</par>
    <par font="Arial" size="12">text 12</par>
    <par font="Times New Roman" size="12">text times 12</par>   
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <html>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par">
        <font>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </font>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="par/@size">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-size: ',.,';')"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="par/@font">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-family: ',.,';')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<html>
   <font style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 24;">text 24</font>
   <font style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12;">text 12</font>
   <font style="font-family: Times New Roman;font-size: 12;">text times 12</font>
</html>
```

Also, you can change the `match="par"` to `match="par[@font or @size]"` if you only want to output `<font>` if it has a `font` or `size` attribute.

Comment: @DevNull this is a good answer but it is not quiet perfect. You are getting an extraneous semicolon on your style attribute value.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin - The trailing semicolon isn't needed, but it doesn't hurt anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Congradulations to DevNull. His was the first correct answer. James answer is wrong.

I am just being very pedantic here, but the actual simplest tightest solution is .... <drumroll/>....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
 <xsl:for-each select="*/par">
  <font style="{ string-join(
   for $a in (@size|@font) return
     concat('font-', if ($a except @font) then 'size' else 'family', ':', $a),
     ';')}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
  </font>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above XSLT 2.0 style-sheet will transform this input ...

```
<doc>
    <par font="Arial" size="24">text 24</par>
    <par font="Arial" size="12">text 12</par>
    <par font="Times New Roman" size="12">text times 12</par>   
    <par font="Courier">No size specified!</par>   
    <par size="16">No font specified!</par>   
</doc>
```

... into this output ...

```
<font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:24">text 24</font>
<font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12">text 12</font>
<font style="font-family:Times New Roman;font-size:12">text times 12</font>
<font style="font-family:Courier">No size specified!</font>
<font style="font-size:16">No font specified!</font>
```

**One small template and no extraneous semicolons in the style attribute value!**

There was no mention of what XSLT version was required. So if the OP is on XSLT 1.0, then this solution may not be useful to the OP.

Comment: B transform is done by IE I just do some search and it seems to accept only XSLT-1.0. I add the tag.